# How To Switch A Bit In An Integer?

Tags: integer, bit-manipulation

I have an integer and I would like to switch 1 bit in it from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0. I don't know its state. How do I do that in 1 statement ?

- using `& | ~ ^`
- avoiding `if else`

(added xor operator)

Comment: This reads like homework.

Comment: @travis Not really a knock on merit. (Although "too localized" applies considering the inane restrictions.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common operation, and there is ample instruction available. For example, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation#Bit_manipulation_in_the_C_programming_language).

Set a bit

```
bit_fld |= (1 << n)
```

Clear a bit

```
bit_fld &= ~(1 << n)
```

Toggle a bit

```
bit_fld ^= (1 << n)
```

Test a bit

```
bit_fld & (1 << n)
```

Comment: Yup. I've never used the bitwise XOR operator yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to toggle a particular bit then use [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) (`^`) operation. Look into the XOR truth table to figure out the answer.

Comment: Removed the c macro sample I had in my answer as I felt this might be a homework.

Answer (score 1):

To set the bit Use the bitwise OR operator (|) to set a bit.

```
number |= 1 << x;
```

That will set bit x.

To Clear a bit use the bitwise AND operator (&) to clear a bit.

```
number &= ~(1 << x);
```

That will clear bit x. You must invert the bit string with the bitwise NOT operator (~), then AND it.

Toggling a bit

```
The XOR operator (^) can be used to toggle a bit.
```

number ^= 1 << x;

Answer (score 0):

To flip a bit, you can XOR the input number with another number with the bit you're flipping set. [Java based example](http://ideone.com/UU7z8C):

```
int a = 0b1001;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(a));
a = a ^ 0b0100; // flip third LSB
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(a));
a = a ^ 0b0100; // flip it back
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(a));
```

XOR isn't one of the allowed operators you mention, but it [can be defined in terms of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Equivalencies.2C_elimination.2C_and_introduction) <sub>[(example)](http://ideone.com/UU7z8C)</sub>:

```java
int xor(int p, int q) {
    return (p & ~q) | (~p & q);
}
```

(Inline this expression as needed.)